# Nginx: Redirect both http and https root to subdirectory

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, 301-redirect

I'm attempting to redirect the root domain for both http and https in nginx to the same subdirectory (https):

So e.g.

```
http://example.com -> https://example.com/subdirectory

https://example.com -> https://example.com/subdirectory
```

As simple as this seemed to me, I'm struggling to achieve this. I've tried using variations of rewrites and return 301, but always end up with a redirect loop.

My current config (causing the loop):

```
server {
        listen      80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name/subdirectory;
        }
server {
        listen 443 ssl spdy;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name/subdirectory;
    }
```

So basically, i'm trying to redirect to the same subdirectory on https from the root domain, whether the root domain is requested via http or https.

Comment: Please post your nginx config. Without that, we don't know what's wrong with your config

Comment: Yep, sorry, am about to do that now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This configuration will do what you want:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name/subdirectory;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    location = / {
        return 301 https://$server_name/subdirectory;
    }
}
```

The `= /` specifiers means a full match, so it matches only the exact root URI of the virtual server.

Comment: Thank you for this. I wasn't aware of the `= /` specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it won't work if you don't exclude location subdirectory from this behaviour for the ssl vhost.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name/subdirectory;

}

server {

    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server_name example.com;

    location /subdirectory {
        # Your stuff
    }

    location = / {
        return 301 https://$server_name/subdirectory;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80:
    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name/subdirectory/;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    location = / {
        return 301 https://$server_name/subdirectory/;   
    }
}
```

See how I added the trailing slash at the end, this is very important otherwise you will get redirect loops.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with some "tweaks"...

```
server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/<DOMAIN_NAME>-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/<DOMAIN_NAME>-error.log;
    listen <PORT_PROXY>;
    server_name <DOMAIN_NAME>;

    location /<SUBDIRECTORY> {
        proxy_pass http://<RESOURCE_IP>:<RESOURCE_PORT>/<SUBDIRECTORY>;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:<PORT_PROXY>;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location = / {
        return 301 https://$server_name/<SUBDIRECTORY>;
    }

}
```

**Thanks! =D**